# Best way to design a Java class that contains an generated ID

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am trying to design an API which involves book a transaction to the system. The system will then generate a transaction ID that uniquely identifies the transaction.

I would like to define the Transaction class as a immutable one, like this:

```
public class Transaction {
    private final double quantity;
    private final BigDecimal price;

    public Order(double quantity, BigDecimal price) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public double getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

The client call the API to create a new transaction:

```
public void storeTransaction(Transaction t)
```

But if I do this, how can I store the generated transaction ID?

**1. Option 1**

I can add an mutable state to the transaction class:

```
public class Transaction {
    private final double quantity;
    private final BigDecimal price;
    private String transactionID;

    public Order(double quantity, BigDecimal price) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public double getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getTransactionID() {
        return transactionID;
    }

    public void setTransactionID(String id) {
        transactionID = id;
    }
}
```

But this will make the Transaction class mutable.

**Option 2**

I can keep using the immutable Transaction and expose the API like this:

```
public String storeTransaction(Transaction t)
```

So instead of save the transaction id in the Transaction class, I could return it to our API user. But this does not look perfect for me as well because the user has to maintain an ID->Transaction relationship.

What is the best practice for designing this type of scenario?

Comment: Can a `Transaction` exist without an ID? If so, ID should not be an attribute of Transaction, maybe use a subclass `SavedTransaction`. If not, include the ID in the constructor. You might change `void storeTransaction(Transaction t)` to `Transaction storeTransaction(double quantity, BigDecimal price)`, i.e., create and return the transaction at the place where presumably the ID is generated.

Comment: The typical default for handling data like this in Java is JPA, which uses mutable objects as an architectural decision.

Comment: @floxbr Alternatively, the ID is generated internally to the class and should not be supplied by any outside source.

Comment: @ZZZ Note that your code has a class named `Transaction` with a supposed constructor named `Order`. Be sure that these names match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the id in your constructor:

```
public class Transaction {
    private final double quantity;
    private final BigDecimal price;
    private String transactionID;

    public Order(double quantity, BigDecimal price) {
        this.transactionID = this.generateID();
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Now just implement a `generateID()` method to fill in the details.

Answer (score 1):

Your `storeTransaction()` method could return the saved transaction which also contained the id.

```
public Transaction storeTransaction(Transaction t) {
    ...
}
```

And your `Transaction` class could have two constructors, one with the transaction id (for when it is known) and one without.

Your `storeTransaction()` method could save transaction with no id is present or if an id was present:

1. throw an exception if you want to keep your transactions immutable in your database or
2. update the existing transaction if you don't need immutability in the database.

The `storeTransaction()` method would return a new Transaction object containing all the details of the saved transaction (if it didn't throw an exception, of course).

Answer (score -1):

Well, finalizing it does not make it that immutable. It is quite easy to change a final field in java, even easier than accessing a private field. Therefore I would create a mutable field, but it's setter does only work if the field is currently null. So you can only set it once (when it's generated). If the field is not null then you can throw an `IllegalStateException`